# MariaDB multiple DB split between multiple servers - can I query like they all are on the same instance?

Tags: php, mariadb

I have this scenario: I have a PhP 5.6 application that connects to a MariaDB (edit: I stated MySQL before but is not correct) instance.
In this instance I have a "master" DB and a DB for each firm using the application. Each new firm -> a new DB.

The number of DBs is growing exponentially and we are considering a way to split these client's DBs between multiple MariaDB servers.

The problem is that there are many queries that join between client's DB and master DB, so we cannot blindly just connect to another Host.

Is it possible to setup a MariaDB instance that have databases in other hosts, but still "virtually sees them" as on the same instance (so that cross DB queries still work) ?

I tried to google this without success.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I've found out about Federated Tables that might be the solution.
Question is, we like to split DBs between servers because we might have a number of DBs in the range of 50.000-100.000 and we fear about performances.
If I create these DBs locally all with federated tables, will this solve my issue or are we still facing performance issues?

Comment: Can I ask the reasoning why you need a database for each client?  The answer will dictate the architectural decisions you need to make.

Comment: @cherrysoft unfortunately I haven't made this decision. I have to just maintain this project and this structure cannot change....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need FederatedX to get to the *common* database from the client dbs.

And "sharding" is putting *several* clients on each of *several* servers.  Not one client on each of 50K servers.

Or is there some requirement you have not provided yet?

How big are these "clients"?  How big is the largest?  Are there security concerns if multiple clients live on the same server?  In the same MariaDB instance?  In the same *table*?

Have you already set up some form of Proxy to route a client request to the server for that client?  Or are you expecting the client to own his server?

Etc, etc.

Keep in mind that reaching into a 'federated' table is slow, in some cases *orders of magnitude slower*.  So work hard on minimizing the need for federation.

Another approach would be less burden on the individual queries, but more admin effort -- duplicate the "common" database across all of the shards.  This could probably be done via replication by having the "common" server be a Master and all the shards by Slaves.

Comment: Hi Rick thatnk you for your reply.
Yes, in the end I've figured out that FederatedX is the solution.
There is no particular security / proxy / communication concern: we will own all the DB servers, we are just concerned about the growth..we have right now 20k client DBs and the machine is starting to suffer, while we expect to grow up to 50k in the next couple of months.
The DBs are "rather small", I don't expect one to grow more then 50-100MB for instance.

Comment: My main limitation is that:
- i have an application that "thinks" to just have 1 connection, to the original DB server
- i have cross-DB queries.
With that in mind i have two options:
- federate the tables of most of the client's DB from now one (but i fear that having a server that "manages" 10Ks of DBs, even if not phisically, might still have performance issues)
- adjust slightly the app to make the DB connection variable and federate the tables of the "master DB" (the common one with all the configs) in each new DB server

Comment: @MarcelloGarini - See if what I added gives you some more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase it's fast easy more then MySQL v
But if you need to this 
You can make a simple API on the other server that has the instance for MySQL this API will run your query on the server and return back the results

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Fact is, i'd like to find first, if possible, a solution that won't impact my code at all, so that's why I was looking for a infrascructural answer first

Comment: I think it will not impact your code but can you give us a simple  prediction for the code style you want may i find something could help you